# Insert table in document with 2 columns layout?

Tags: tables, two-column

I need to insert the following table to a document that has a 2 columns layout:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Three possible values of the difference in the probability of course completion of students assigned to effective versus ineffective treatment arms.}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{rccc}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\multirow{2}{*}{Mean effect size, averaging across countries}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Probability\\ of course completion (\%)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{Difference}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ineffective\\ arms\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Effective\\ arms\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
Small & 4.6 & 5.3 & 0.8 \\
Medium & 4.6 & 8.5 & 3.9 \\
Large & 4.6 & 13.3 & 8.7
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

When I compile the PDF, the table does not fit in one column. This is what it looks like:

[image: badtable]

The [style](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/acm_proc_article-sp.cls) file and the [template](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/sigproc-sp.tex) that I am using are available [here](http://www.acm.org/sigs/publications/proceedings-templates).

How can I fix this?

---

Alternatively I can use this code:

```
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Three possible values of the difference in the probability of course completion of students assigned to effective versus ineffective treatment arms.}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{rccc}
\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\multirow{2}{*}{Mean effect size, averaging across countries}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Probability\\ of course completion (\%)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\multirow{2}{*}{Difference}} \\
\multicolumn{1}{c}{} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ineffective\\ arms\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Effective\\ arms\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{} \\
Small & 4.6 & 5.3 & 0.8 \\
Medium & 4.6 & 8.5 & 3.9 \\
Large & 4.6 & 13.3 & 8.7
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

and I get this:

[image: badtable2]

Comment: try `\begin{table*} ...\end{table*}`

Comment: that kind works but not really well. Basically it uses 2 columns instead of 1. A better solution would break 'Mean effect size, averaging across countries' in 2 or more lines and keep the table in one column. Thanks @touhami!

Comment: ok, yes `\multicolumn{1}{p{2cm}}{\multirow{2}{*}{Mean effect siz..` or p{3cm}

Comment: much closer, but the text goes over the other columns. I updated my question showing that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variant, also with `makecell` and `siunitx`, and `booktabs` and `caption`:

```
\documentclass{acm_proc_article-sp}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{multirow, tabularx, caption, booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\renewcommand\cellalign{rc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{table-format=1.1}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[2]%
\begin{table}[! htbp]\captionsetup{font=bf}
  \centering\setlength\tabcolsep{8pt}
  \caption{Three possible values of the difference in the probability of course completion of students assigned to effective versus ineffective treatment arms.}
  \label{my-label}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XSS[table-format=2.1]S}
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\thead{Probability of \\ course completion (\%)}}
    & \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-3}
    \multirowcell{-4}[0.3ex]{Mean effect size,\\averaging\\ across countries}& {\thead{Ineffective\\ arms}} & {\thead{Effective\\ arms}} & {\multirowcell{-1}[-1ex]{Difference}}
    \\[-1.4ex]
    \midrule
    Small & 4.6 & 5.3 & 0.8 \\
    Medium & 4.6 & 8.5 & 3.9 \\
    Large & 4.6 & 13.3 & 8.7
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\lipsum[3-8]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like how your solution looks, but is not working for me. See http://imgur.com/Qks0QQx

Comment: You obtained such a result with the *exact  code*  in my answer?

Comment: Yep, I'm using sharelatex.com. https://www.sharelatex.com/project/55bbc6eed2ca043251bda1eb

Comment: Solved! I'm sorry, it was a problem with my editor, which added three spurious `&` after `Mean average size`. Please see the corrected code.

Comment: You're welcome! Always glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

Problem is construction of your table. Since you didn't provide MWE, I use one from some old picture ... anyway, obtained table is 80 mm wide. This should fit in one column. Try code below in your document and see, if this is what you looking for.

```
\documentclass[11pt, border=1mm,
               preview]{standalone}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \linespread{0.9}
\centering
\caption{Three possible values of the difference in the probability of course completion of students assigned to effective versus ineffective treatment arms.}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{rSSS}
\thead{Mean effect size,\\
       averaging across \\countries} 
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{\thead{Probability of \\ 
                                  course completion\\
                                  (\%)}}
            &   {\thead{Difference}}                           \\
    &   {\thead{Ineffective\\ arms}}
        &   {\thead{Effective\\ arms}} 
            &                                                   \\
    \hline
Small   & 4.6   & 5.3   & 0.8 \\
Medium  & 4.6   & 8.5   & 3.9 \\
Large   & 4.6   & 13.3  & 8.7
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
        \end{document}
```

For above table I use two packages: `makecell`, from which I use `thead` macro  (with it replace `multirow`) and `siunitx` for column tyle `S`, which gives nicer align of numbers.

[image]

Tables usually has top and bottom rules. I didn't inclede them, because in your example are not presented. Fro their use, I suggest to use `booktab` package.